# Allowing the user to add data to a table jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, html-table, addition

I need the user to enter their own data to the table. Is this possible?

I want to have text fields where the user can enter their ID, score etc, and then when they click an add button, their data will be included in the table.

(Ignore the hyper-links on each ID, not using them at the moment).

Code (updated to what I had tried)

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
         <h1>Top 10</h1>
        <button id="btn1">Add Scores</button>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="name">ID:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  />
</div>  
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="name">Score:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  />
</div>  

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="name">Course</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  />
</div>  



    <table data-role="table" id="table-column-toggle" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-priority="2">Rank</th>
          <th>Student ID</th>
          <th data-priority="3">Course</th>
          <th data-priority="1">Meeting negotiated target</th>
          <th data-priority="5">Score (pts)</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Kane" data-rel="external">B</a></td>
          <td>Computing</td>
          <td><img src="tick.jpg"/></td>
          <td>229</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>2</th>
          <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casablanca_(film)" data-rel="external">B</a></td>
          <td>Network Computing</td>
          <td><img src="cross.jpg"/></td>
          <td>201</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>3</th>
          <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godfather" data-rel="external">B</a></td>
          <td>Computer Forensics</td>
          <td><img src="tick.jpg"/></td>
          <td>194</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>4</th>
          <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gone_with_the_Wind_(film)" data-rel="external">B</a></td>
          <td>Computing</td>
          <td><img src="tick.jpg"/></td>
          <td>194</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>5</th>
          <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_of_Arabia_(film)" data-rel="external">B</a></td>
          <td>Computing</td>
          <td><img src="cross.jpg"/></td>
          <td>159</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>6</th>
          <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove" data-rel="external">B</a></td>
          <td>Computer Science</td>
          <td><img src="tick.jpg"/></td>
          <td>122</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>7</th>
          <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Graduate" data-rel="external">B</a></td>
          <td>ICT</td>
          <td><img src="tick.jpg"/></td>
          <td>122</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>8</th>
          <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Oz_(1939_film)" data-rel="external">B</a></td>
          <td>Computing</td>
         <td><img src="cross.jpg"/></td>
          <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>9</th>
          <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singin%27_in_the_Rain" data-rel="external">B</a></td>
          <td>ICT</td>
          <td><img src="tick.jpg"/></td>
          <td>85</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>10</th>
          <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception" data-rel="external">B</a></td>
          <td>Computer Science</td>
          <td><img src="cross.jpg"/></td>
          <td>78</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
```

Comment: Post your failing attempt! Appending content to TABLE works just as for any other element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first.

Your inputs must have distinct/unique ID/Names, like:

```
Rank: <input type="text" name="ScoreRank" id="ScoreRank" value=""  />    
ID: <input type="text" name="ScoreId" id="ScoreId" value=""  />    
Course: <input type="text" name="ScoreCourse" id="ScoreCourse" value=""  />
Target: <input type="text" name="ScoreTarget" id="ScoreTarget" value=""  />    
Points: <input type="text" name="ScorePoints" id="ScorePoints" value=""  />
```

With that in mind ou could use jQuery to traverse the inputs and add another table row...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn1').on('click',AddScore);
});

function AddScore()
{
    var jqTableBody = $('#table-column-toggle tbody');
    var sTRTemplate = '<tr>' + 
                      '    <td>{Rank}</td>' +
                      '    <td>{Id}</td>' +
                      '    <td>{Course}</td>' +
                      '    <td>{Target}</td>' +
                      '    <td>{Points}</td>' +
                      '</tr>';

    var sTRAppend = sTRTemplate;

    $('div[data-role="fieldcontain"] input:text').each(function(){
        switch(this.id) {
            case 'ScoreRank' :  sTRAppend = sTRAppend.replace('{Rank}', this.value); break;
            case 'ScoreID' :  sTRAppend = sTRAppend.replace('{Id}', this.value); break;
            case 'ScoreCourse' :  sTRAppend = sTRAppend.replace('{Course}', this.value);     break;
            case 'ScoreTarget' :  sTRAppend = sTRAppend.replace('{Target}', this.value);     break;
            case 'ScorePoints' :  sTRAppend = sTRAppend.replace('{Points}', this.value);     break;
        }
    })
    jqTableBody.append(sTRAppend);
}
```

AS you asked follows here a working fiddle for that. [Fiddle Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/M6cB2/1/)

Comment: That is great thanks!, could you add this in a js fiddle with the current code I posted?, I am having problems integrating it in to my code.

Comment: I've added Fiddle solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example, though not as fancy as Rogers.

http://jsfiddle.net/gv54s/

Here is some sample just because I had to put it, check the jsfiddle for it all.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#theform').submit(function(){

        // make remove button and event
        var but = $('<button>remove</button>').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
        // make button td
        var buttontd = $('<td></td>').append(but);

        // make row
        var tr = $('<tr><td>'+$('#1').val()+'</td><td>'+$('#2').val()+'</td><td>'+$('#3').val()+'</td></tr>').append(buttontd);

        // add row to table
        $('#thetable').append(tr);

        // return false so form is not submitted
        return false;
    });
});
```